# Which of these three systems need its RAM to be upgraded and why

Tags: memory, ramdisk

These are the images of 'Memory' section of Resource Monitor for 3 systems; The two with 8GB RAM have core i7 cpu while the one with 4GB of RAM has core i5 cpu; Based on these graphs which of these systems needs (or can be benefited) by adding more RAM?

**Update 1:** The system with 8GB RAM (3768MB Free) is mostly used for playing movies and web browsing; The other systems (8GB and 4GB RAM) are used for heavy visualization (multiple VMs) and feature rich graphic applications such Photoshop and Illustrator;

**Please say Why and how you can tell;**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: on its face, none of them at their present workload. RAM just adds capacity, so adding more ram does no good at all, unless you are already running out of it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  As-is this just looks like you're asking us to do homework for you, which is a no-no when you've shown no research effort, and have no specific point you need help with.  The easy answer to "which can benefit?" is "all of them", because at no point in time has anyone ever said "man I wish I had LESS RAM in this system, it performs better that way!". ;)

Comment: it's not a homework. I'm just wondering which of these specs matters when we want to decide to upgrade RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the "blue" is unused in that it can be instantly rewritten without any impact. The dark blue "standby" section indicates things Windows is *guessing you might want* (read: frequently used) and it has pre-loaded it into memory in order to present you with it as quickly as possible should you request it. You can consider this standby memory as "free." Notice that the value quoted as "available" is both types of "Blue memory."

The point where you need to upgrade ram for more capacity is the point where the whole bar is "grey + green + orange" all the time (or at least the times when it matters to you).

As long as your usage pattern does not use the full capacity of the RAM installed, then you will not see any benefit.

In your screen captures, even the worst-case machine still has about 1/3 of total RAM capacity unused.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing a helpful answer rather than asking why I'm asking